# Propiedad value en un textarea html?

Tags: php, html

pues mi pregunta es si es posible, tengo este codigo de un formulario que recoje datos y pues todos los value los asigna menos en el textarea, ya comprobe que la variable no este vacia.

```
$eq_vehiculo = $equipamiento;
echo "<script>alert('$eq_vehiculo')</script>";

<textarea name="text_equipamiento"  style="height:150px" placeholder="Ingrese detalles del vehiculo" value="<?php echo $eq_vehiculo; ?>" required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La `etiqueta` va de esta forma:

```
<textarea name="text_equipamiento"  style="height:150px" placeholder="Ingrese detalles del vehiculo" required><?php echo $eq_vehiculo; ?></textarea>
```